# Floating sketchpen?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, home-experiment, bernoulli-equation

This post is about an experiment of mine , which was for me, remarkably interesting!

Why do I post it here?

I'm interested in knowing the physics behind this.

## MATERIALS USED

[image: holding the pen]
A light weight sketchpen.

## THE EXPERIMENT

I took a sketch pen, and held it by its tail. 
After some practice, I could manage to fling the pen up in the air *while* getting it to spin about the axis passing through its length.

So I had a *spinning pen , going up in the air and moving through unusual paths*.

I repeated the process many times to arrive at a conclusion. 
 It seemed as if a force acted on the pen, **perpendicular to its length, on the side which has a spin complementary to the direction of air flow**.

So if I flung the pen up vertically, it would  *first accelerate towards one direction during the ascend, and then, accelerate in the opposite direction during the descend.*

Now for the BEST PART:

I threw the pen, with its length parallel to the ground horizontally with spin in an **anticlockwise** direction w.r.t the ground. It hit the ground earlier than expected.

Next , tried the same with **clockwise** spin. As I expected, the pen stayed in the air for a longer than usual time.

I gradually increased the the spin to such an extent, that the pen *appeared to float in the air !*
[image: Diagrammatic representation]
It had apparently *no vertical acceleration*!
It just moved horizontally with a constant velocity, till it hit the side walls and landed.

It seemed *magical* to my family and friends !

Now I wonder what made the pen fly.

Whatever it is, I know that it depends on the spin velocity, ***spin direction***  and the air flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known [Magnus Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) effect described by NASA here : [Lift of rotating Cylinder](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/cyl.html). Hope this helps :)

[image]

Comment: So, can't we make lightweight flying vehicles with rapidly spinning cylinders instead of tyres?

Comment: Yes, a chopper would be pretty straightforward, a plane a bit trickier. Neither would be more efficient than existing designs of course, but a small chopper with rotating cylinders would be a fun toy :) A two-propeller helicopter also should work, as there is no principle difference between propellers and rotating cylinders. Trickier with a plane as the cylinders would replace the wings and the angular momentum would need to be compensated from nosing the plane down. Plus something would need to propell the plane forward. It would be hard for it to take off.

Comment: Interesting. Infact, I found that there really does exist the magnus effect planes. See https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DK6geOms33Dk&ved=0ahUKEwiDlqznob3WAhWLtI8KHWxSAEoQwqsBCCYwAA&usg=AFQjCNG5R-VagKrIZM85UQeX9_2g1P5Jtw

Comment: Like I expected, hard to take off. The guy had to throw it every time. A helicopter would be much cooler. Make one :)

Comment: I would like to, once I'm out of school!!